# Is using functions a good practice?

Tags: php, return

I have a Handler.php that manages the user-input post from several pages.

In several parts of my Handler.php I need to perform the `same` query.

Right now I have the same code repeated in different parts of Handler.php.

Would it be a better approach to call a function and then return the result?

I know it would work, but, since I'm really amateur, I would appreciate experts advice.

Comment: Can you share some code with us, or maybe explain your question a little bit more?

Comment: The general rule of thumb is DRY (Don't repeat yourself).... in other words, if you have the same block of code in several different places, then make it a function

Comment: Code should never be repeated, unless you got a good reason

Comment: @BenoîtLatinier the're shouldn't be a good reason enough to repeat your code. Couldn't think of a reason that wouldn't be beaten by the maintainability. Except you're just trying something super fast and then write it down in "normal" code.

Comment: @WesselvanderLinden my question is not directly related to a specific code, but to code conception. I can see that people don't like it (downvotes), but for me was important to know about DRY (Mark Baker & Benoit Latinier). Thanks!

Comment: @user1726522 then this question would be better suited for the programmers stack exchange, maybe you can create a custom flag or ask on meta for a migration to that platform. Stackoverflow is for broken/buggy code, where programmers is for the conceptional part of programming :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always better to call a function at multiple locations where the same code needs to be executed!

It's much more readable and maintainable, because every change you need to do to the function must only be done in the function, not on N locations within your whole code where you repeated your code.

It's really bad practice to repeat code, you should always try to plan and structure your code in a way that you only need code once in your project.

Also it would be good to have every operations with the database in one class. That way you can find your code which works with the DB pretty fast.

Just imagine this:

```
//DataHandler.php

/* ... some code ... */

mysqli_query($dbCon, "SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE X = Y");

/* ... some other code ... */

mysqli_query($dbCon, "SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE X = Y");

/* ... much more code ... */

mysqli_query($dbCon, "SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE X = Y");
```

Now you need to change something in your query

```
//DataHandler.php

/* ... some code ... */

mysqli_query($dbCon, "SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE Y = X");

/* ... some other code ... */

mysqli_query($dbCon, "SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE Y = X");

/* ... much more code ... */

mysqli_query($dbCon, "SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE X = Y");
```

**WHOOPS** you missed to change it at one location and now you got a, maybe pretty huge, bug in your system and you will shed tears in searching this error.

So it's much more better to do this:

```
//DataHandler.php

/* ... some code ... */

$data = selectSomething($someDataYouNeedToCheck);

/* ... some other code ... */

$data = selectSomething($someDataYouNeedToCheck);

/* ... much more code ... */

$data = selectSomething($someDataYouNeedToCheck);

function selectSomething($y){
    mysqli_query($dbCon, "SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE X = ".$y);
    // return the result after working with it
}
```

Now you only need to change the code within the function and can't miss a part in your project! You got **a single point of failure**. You know where a error occures because there's only place where it could occure!

Comment: thumbs up for this awesome answer showing why encapsulating functionality is a must!